# Communicate over network without knowing device IP address

Tags: java, c, linux, ethernet

I am working on design of a device that are installed on **clients networks**. Currently there is about 180 devices installed arround the world. One major concern is to access them for debugging purpose later.

**Context :**

All devices work the same.

- OS is Linux
- Default mode is DHCP but sometimes Static IP

Currently the method to get addresses is :

Log on a computer of the client with any remote desktop software available and search with :

- DHCP address in router's leases table (most of the time clients doesn't know their credentials)
- Angry IP scanner, scan for port 22 (slow)
- ping the name of the device (doesn't always work)

**Expecting :**

Actually I know it is possible to communicate with devices on network without knowing its IP address by broadcasting on the network but not found any example yet or start point. I would like to write a small Java program that will be able to broadcast on a network to :

- List every devices with their IP
- Assign IP address to device and/or other functions

Remember : I would like to find devices that have no keyboard, screen or other UI. If I receive a unit from a client (for debug purposes) that was configurated for example with 10.1.1.100 and my computer is on 192.168.1.110 (on the same switch), I want to be able first to know the IP address of this device, second, be able to send a SET IP command (I'll manage how to handle it once I'm able to send data).

For the *server* part of the device, I don't mind, it could be done in C++ or script... This will probably needed to answer to broadcast and receive requests.

**So far**, I've been able to create a small UDP client and server.

Client in Java using `DatagramSocket`, server in C using `recvfrom()`.

The problem with this solution is that my computer need to have the same network mask as the device, example :

- Device has 192.168.2.217
- Computer has 192.168.1.110
- My computer will need 255.255.0.0 as netmask, ortherwise I will not be able to broadcast 192.168.255.255.

**Seaching more**, the need to change the local computer netmask to meed broadcasting range seems to be a limitation of Java...

```
new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, InetAddress.getByName("255.255.255.255"), PORT); // not working
new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, InetAddress.getByName("192.168.255.255"), PORT); // working only if netmask is 255.255.0.0
```

I think I will need to go deeper in network protocols to do it the way I want and that I know it is possible.

Comment: To be honest, it sounds like you just need to manage your network better. Set them all to DHCP, and either assign them IPs based on their known MAC address, and/or make sure their hostnames are set so they can be tracked from the DHCP requests.

Comment: These devices are installed arround the world on clients networks, you know, the kind of clients that don't know what is a router, I totally have no control on their networks, that's why I want an easy solution to find them if I need.

Comment: Broadcast traffic is confined to the local subnet. So no, you cannot broadcast to another network around the world.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart When I do debugging, I do it remotly, from their network.

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie mention it in the question

Comment: I understand now. It wasn't terribly clear from your question. I think some sort of UDP listener (using [`recvfrom`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recvfrom)) would allow you to pick up brodcast (ie. 192.168.1.255) traffic on the subnet.  From there, you could have the device simply reply back some sort of packet that lets you know information about the device.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Will it work if for example the device has an IP address on another subnet? I've seen something like that but of course the company will not share the code! :)

Comment: UPnP? That was my first thought. Is it an option? You would just need the Discovery-Part.

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie Yes, the device would reply,but good luck getting the router to forward that broadcast packet to another subnet.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Thank you, I'll give a try tomorrow! Time to sleep.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Tried, but can't do exactly what I want so far, updated the question with my results.